# How to show "Open in appstore" to install via Universal Linking (apple-app-site-association) in swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

Am creating an application for stock market related things. Here, I am using Universal Linking features. It is working correctly like, When app is installed, I tap the link it open the app correctly. If app is not installed, it open the link in safari.

But my issue is, it doesn't show "Open in Appstore" to download the app from appstore when the link is opened in safari.

I created app id with enabled the associated domain, created apple-app-site-association file and successfully hosted the file in web server and set the applink in Xcode project capabilities.

Please guide me to achieve when the app is not installed, it open the link in safari. But doesn't ask the user to download the app from appstore.

Note: App is also available in AppStore. And I didn't use Branch.io

Answer (score 1):

I did it by myself.

Step 1: I created apple-app-site-association(AASA) file and placed it in root of my server.

Step 2: I set MIME type to AASA file and set my app appstore url as metadata for the link.

Step 3: Then I enabled associated domain in AppId from Apple developer account.

Step 4: I enabled my Xcode entitlements.

That’s it. Now it’s works what I expected.

Comment: HI @Sabs, I have the same issue, but I don't understand how these steps are different from what you did first. Is all magic contained in step 2?

Comment: Hi @igrrik, Yes step 2 is important. We have to set AppStore url into that webpages metadata.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any example or tutorial on how to properly set this metadata?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the user to automatically be prompted with an "Open in App Store" modal after clicking a Branch link, you should [disable Deepviews](https://dashboard.branch.io/web/deepviews). This way, the user will be redirected to the Passive Deepview in Safari, along with the App Store prompt. You could also set the Passive Deepview on your Branch dashboard or on a per-link basis.

To learn more about Deepviews, please visit the docs [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/deep-views/).

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for your quick reply and sorry for my late response. Here I didn't use Branch SDK.